# How to retrieve data from Mono<T> on java

Tags: java, mongodb, project-reactor

I have an entity like this:

```
public class Period implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String id;
    private PeriodType type;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private Long lastQuranId;
    private Long lastUvoiceId;
    private List<Integer> exclusiveContentTypeOrder;
}
```

and i have

```
Mono<Period> periodMono = periodReactiveRepository.findOneByTypeAndStartDateLessThanEqualAndEndDateGreaterThanEqual(type,
                currentDate, currentDate);
```

My question is if I want to get StartDate how to get that?

I have try use this

```
Date startDate = (Date) periodMono.subscribe(period-> period.getStartDate());
```

My question is this code it is correct or not? If not how to get `StartDate` from my `Mono`?

Comment: you can use `yourMono.map(...)`

Comment: what i must use on .map().... i confuse use yourMono.map(..) can you explain it ?

Comment: Date startDate =  periodMono.map(period -> { return period.getStartDate();}); i have use this but i think it is error... could you explain and give example

Answer (score 0):

**Blocking way:**

Mono completes successfully by emitting an element at some point in time.

```
Date startDate = periodMono.block().getStartDate();
```

When you are calling block method, it will be block until result arrive. So actually  you may miss the reactive non blocking feature.
To get more control, you can set an explicit duration also.

**Non-Blocking Way**

As you mentioned you can get in a non-blocking way using the subscribe() method.

```
periodMono.subscribe(period-> {Date startDate = period.getStartDate(); //continue ur operation });
```

you cannot cast Disposable into date object. [Ref](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-from-mono)